# error with Xyce Gnuplot.py

Tags: python

I am using Xyce which is a circuit simulator. I am using it to export a .CSV file and a .prn file. I found Xycegnuplot.py "https://github.com/OpenXyce/Xyce/blob/master/utils/gnuplotXyce.py". I am trying to use it to plot my output variables from Xyce, howver, every time I run gnuplotXyce.py as mentioned by its author I get an error " Import Error" at the "from finblock import findblock" line and I don't know what is that error.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use Xyce, you should probably get the official version from Sandia National Laboratories instead of from the OpenXyce site on github.  This version was forked by an anonymous github user, and has not been updated since last fall.  Since that update, Sandia released Xyce 6.2 and the OpenXyce creator did not import the new release.

You should also probably join the xyce-users group on googlegroups, where the Xyce developers monitor all questions and try to answer them promptly.  It is only by happenstance that I found your question here on stackoverflow.

The "gnuplotXyce.py" script is not really maintained, and might not have been kept working with all the changes that have been made to Xyce since its release.  That said, the python script depends on a number of python modules including gnuplot-py which should be available from http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net.  The "findblock.py" module that you say cannot be found is also present in the "utils" directory of the Xyce source code, alongside gnuplotXyce.py.   If you have the whole utils directory downloaded, this error should go away.

I just tried gnuplotXyce.py on a simple netlist with csv output and it didn't work, so my assumption is that the script was not maintained and will need to be fixed.

The script *does* sort of work if you use the native Xyce standard (.prn) format (i.e. don't specify "format=csv" on your .print line).  Unfortunately, it does not leave the window open after it finishes plotting, so it is rather useless.  If you use the "--ps" option, though, a correct postscript file will be created that can be viewed in any postscript viewer, or printed on a postscript printer (or through a properly set-up Linux CUPS printer that understands postscript).

The CSV format in Xyce was primarily created in order to allow import into spreadsheets such as Excel or OpenOffice-scalc, which programs have their own plotting utilities.

The ".prn" standard format works well in gnuplot.  There is an example of how to use gnuplot to do this display in the document "Using Open Source Schematic Capture Tools With Xyce" on the Sandia Labs Xyce web site (in the documentation and tutorials section).

The official Xyce web site is http://xyce.sandia.gov/